# does jython 2.7 compatible with python 3.6 code

Tags: python, jython

does anyone know which jython version compatible with python 3.6. I checked the jython release note, didn't get a clear clue. Thanks

Comment: what are you asking? python2.7 is not compatible with python3.6 code in general... i dont know why jython would be any different

Comment: its not python 2.7, its jython 2.7 (a different python implementation in java), I tried to run python 3.6 code in jython, seems some not work

Comment: here is a jython download link: http://www.jython.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 3):

There currently is no official jython 3.x version. There is a [github repro](https://github.com/jython/jython3), put that is unfinished. You can try that, put it will propably not work. So no, I don't believe you can use CPython 3.6 code and use it on jython without any code changes. It would be the easiest to use CPython or change the code to fit python 2.7

Comment: Thanks for the info here! I found Jython is very convenient for running java api in python. Would you please recommend other methods for running java libraries in python 3.6 if knows?

Comment: searched online, found PY4J, does anyone know is PY4J works for python 3.6

Comment: @user9571515 Check the download page. There are versions for python 3.x but they're untested. Most likely they will work.

Comment: thanks! will run a test, hope it works